# "Edits must be at least 6 characters", why?

Tags: discussion, furigana

I just wanted to add furigana to a good answer written by someone else but I get the following error:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

This seems like a silly rule especially as I just wanted to add furigana to make an answer easier to understand.

Comment: This really is a bit of a bugbear at times. Oftentimes an edit for furigana doesn't meet this arbitrary requirement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only applies to edits made by [<2000 rep users](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) (in particular, it won't affect you any longer) since in this case edits will be added to the review queue and need to be reviewed by two people. I guess the idea behind "at least 6 characters" is that very short edits, i.e. less than 6 characters, aren't worth the time of two reviewers.

Comment: Good point. I didn't know about that 1000rep rule for short edits. I just tested and I was able to edit 3 characters (added furigana) without issue. This seems fine to me. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Six characters may not be a lot, but even a single character can make a difference. A few years ago, I got an email from a client instructing me to **not** change something in a program I was writing for them - but they actually *meant* to type "could you **now** make any further changes" instead. In the context of JLU, I can imagine [さっか](http://jisho.org/word/%E4%BD%9C%E5%AE%B6) being mis-typed as [さか](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%9D%82), or similar.

Comment: @GoBusto Of course, at times there are smart and well-meaning <1000 rep users, like yourself, for which the rule of six characters just is a nuisance. In case you can't edit, you can leave a [comment](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) saying "did you mean to write X instead of Y?" and either the poster him/herself or someone with >1000 rep will notice and edit the post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain this rule is a default enforced in nearly all stackexchange communities. It would probably be removed if it was made a priority, but currently it doesn't seem too big of a problem.

Another possible reason is to avoid short edits, furigana, kanji correction and occasionally a few spelling mistake corrections aren't too much to worry about compared to innacurate information and huge mistakes. Though, in my opinion, all edits are good edits.