# Adding tags is fine, but also fixing a typo gets me 'Edits must be at least 6 characters'

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing

I get 'Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?' for fixing a typo on top of adding tags. Just adding tags would be fine.

Related to [“Edits must be at least 6 characters”, why?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1376/edits-must-be-at-least-6-characters-why), but different.

Answer (score 1):

Editing tags doesn't count towards the "at least 6 characters" rule (unfortunately). So the answer is actually the same as on the linked question ["Edits must be at least 6 characters", why?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1376/1628)

I'm afraid this rule will continue to affect you for another 6-8 weeks or so, until you have gained [enough reputation (now 2000) to "Edit Questions and Answers"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: For workarounds of the character limit see https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/299332